# Linking to libresolv in Android NDK

Tags: android-ndk

I'm trying to port one DNS tool to Android that depends on libresolv (at least to my understanding).

So basically it looks like Android has libresolv (after android-21) since at least the headers are there. But when compiling I get a linker error

```
error: undefined reference to '__ns_parserr'
error: undefined reference to 'p_class'
error: undefined reference to 'p_type'
error: undefined reference to '__ns_name_uncompress'
error: undefined reference to '__ns_initparse'
error: undefined reference to '__ns_msg_getflag'
```

If I've understood correctly (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bionic_(software)) all those should be in libc, but for some reason they are not.

Any advise?

Oh BTW this is the thing I'm trying to port

https://github.com/verisign/dnscap/blob/master/dump_dns.c